# Best practice to review questions already commented

Tags: discussion, review

I sometimes have a bit of time and review new users' posts / answers. Often I see some which is already commented how to be improved. If I agree with the comment I don't want to write similar comment, but also I don't click "no review needed" as the post is not ok, so I just hit skip. Is it ok?

Comment: You can also upvote the comment, which is a good way to say that you agree with it. In certain queues this counts as your review rather than "no action needed".

Comment: Thanks, actually I haven't tried whether I can choose "I'm done" after upvoting the comment, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: [(more)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L3fMs.png)